# How can one obtain the message from state-reverting exception using ethereum clients, when self did not broadcast transaction?

Tags: ethereum, web3js, go-ethereum

Suppose an ethereum smart contract has external function "foo" whose logic has state-reverting exception `require(1 == 0, 'error: you broke the simulation!');`.

If ethereum-client A broadcasts transaction "txA" which is a function call on foo, how can ethereum-client B access the state-reverting message corresponding to "txA"?

edit: by "how can", I mean how can a developer practically enable ethereum-client B to access this data. i.e. Can you please point me in the direction of the correct (lower-level.. not webui) api/rpc call from a particular tool?

Clearly this is possible since block explorers provide such messages for failed transactions. I read through some of the source of etherscan, but their javascript is minimized and not easily readable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've also been digging through the source of go-ethereum, as well as Metamask to find a solution, to no avail. (yet?).

I've also surveyed the list of possible rpc calls to nodes in this network, and the closest thing I found is "getTransactionLogs". Unfortunately, these logs appear to be only for transactions that have been included in blocks, which is not the case when a function reverts.

Answer (score 0):

See this: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39817/are-failed-transactions-included-in-the-blockchain

Failed transactions often are included in the chain.

What you sometimes see, if you're using e.g. MetaMask, is a popup saying "this transaction will fail" that happens *before* the transaction is sent to the chain. This is MetaMask trying to be helpful and prevent you wasting gas. But you can force send the transaction anyway, and you'll get a failed/reverted transaction posted on-chain (like [this one](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xc3e46d6c69191a1bf7d38ceb8545a698d3e045aa55b0624cf0586ba4244ba6da) for [this Solidity source](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x27e8d50700c8d7b7a96acdf1f15628d60db00755#code)).

So to answer the original question, if TxA was posted on-chain, then client B will process it and get the revert message itself. If TxA was not posted on-chain, then there is no record of it.

Comment: I appreciate your theoretical affirmation that it can be done.

My original question was 
` how can ethereum-client B access the state-reverting message corresponding to "txA"?`

So as a developer, using api (or rpc calls) calls from any of the various tools (go-ethereum etc), how can etherum-client B access this data? Which api (or rpc) calls from which tool?

Comment: I use Nethereum, the .NET api, and the call is web3.Eth.GetContractTransactionErrorReason which gets passed a tx hash and returns a string. Sample usage here: http://playground.nethereum.com/csharp/id/1050.

I dont know what the webjs equivalent is. Also, I believe there is still a constraint that the client has to be geth (parity may have some issues).